# Confused about macros using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I want to understand this bit of code

```
#define GET(p) (*(unsigned int*) (p))
```

I learned about pointers but I can't figure out what the statement above means. When I use GET(ptr), am I getting the value at the address ptr points to or the address that ptr contains?

Comment: Macros are just text substitutions. You seem to be asking what `*(unsigned int *)p` does   , that's a separate issue to macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the following.

1. Cast the pointer `p` to the type `unsigned int*`.
2. De-reference the pointer to get the value at that address.

Another way of putting it is that the macro gets the value of the `unsigned int` at the address specified by `p`.

Comment: merlin2011 summarized it nicely.  If these types of expressions confuse you, try getting your hands on a program called 'cdecl'.  It can be quite useful for understanding the meaning of complex expressions.  See here for more info:  http://www.cdecl.org

Comment: Thank you. That makes much more sense.